What does it mean when a Aquarite chlorine generator has a blinking Inspect Cell LED?
I have a saltwater pool and this year when I turned on my Aquarite chlorine generator there was a flashing "Inspect Cell" light.
Question:

What does this mean and what should I do about it?


This is probably covered in the "instructions for use" or "user manual" that comes with the equipment.

Hoping this was posted in order to self-answer, since the answer came 5 minutes after the question. Almost feels like a case of "post the FAQ from the manual one question at a time", though.

I feel like this would have an answer if you searched even a little

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about DIY Home Improvement.

I'm inclined to agree with you, @brhans, something weird about this one. However, we do have lots of pool maintenance questions and have considered them on topic...

After a certain number of hours (5000?), the chlorine generator flashes this light to tell you that you should inspect and clean the salt cell.
This is because the process of generating chlorine from salt may generate some build-up and need to be cleaned.
On the Aquarite generator, you can hold the diagnostic button for 3 seconds to clear this light.  You should only clear the light after you have cleaned the cell.
